# Unable to post an image to server using AFMultipartFormData

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am having problems with uploading images to server. I went over the similar questions, but I can't seem to find a solution.

The server expects an image file with @"avatar" as the key.

this is how I create the image data

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage], 1.0);
    if (imageData != nil)
    {
        [[restClient sharedInstance]updateAvatarWithData:imageData andIfSuccess:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
            if (dict)
            {
                NSLog(@"dict %@",dict);
            }
        } orIfFail:^(NSError *err) {
            if (err)
            {
                NSLog(@"error %@",err);
            }
        }];
    }
```

// send it to server
// restClient.m

```
- (void)updateAvatarWithData:(NSData *)imageData andIfSuccess:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))successBlock orIfFail:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager  = [[restClient sharedInstance] requestManager];
    NSString *url                           = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/somePath", BASEURL];

    [manager POST:url parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (successBlock)
    {
    successBlock(responseObject);
    }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (failureBlock)
    {
    failureBlock(error);
    }
    }];
```

This is the response I am getting

```
lldb) po [operation responseString]
{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"User","field":"avatar","code":null}]}

(lldb) po error
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: client error (422)" UserInfo=0x1702f0c80 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17443aa0> { URL: url } { status code: 422, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
"Set-Cookie" = "request_method=POST; path=/; secure, XSRF-TOKEN=gMHgjVq7F7fUwoDChpWH0mAwnDxkfGxPg8RzdKdk1g%3D%3D; path=/; secure,; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=315";
"access-control-allow-credentials" = true;
com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: client error (422)}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: @rob, I test the endpoint with postman and verified that the endpoint works. I ll look into Charles but I believe the missing piece is that I need to set @"avatar" key differently but I not sure how...

Comment: @rob, I have added the full request ( this is the only method that is giving me problems right now so no problems on the shared manager)

Comment: Did you try to change `fileName:@"avatar"` to `fileName:@"avatar.jpg"`. On postman the process of submitting an image to server is a bit different than in code.